# python package install outside of IPython

Tags: python

I am trying to install package scikit-learn from the spyder in anaconda.

But there's an error message:

> The Python package manager (pip) can only be used from outside of
>   IPython. Please reissue the `pip` command in a separate terminal or
>   command prompt.

is there any way to install it outside of IPython of Spyder in Anaconda?

Thanks

Comment: You input the pip command in spyder right? It should be typed in command line, also if you are using anaconda, it is better using conda to install, https://anaconda.org/anaconda/scikit-learn

Comment: where is the command line in spyder?

Comment: are you using windows? and how did you start spyder

Comment: I'm using macOS, I start anaconda first and then start spyder in it

Comment: find Anaconda Prompt, start it then type the pip in, but I think anaconda install already include scikit-learn

Comment: where can I possibly find the Anaconda Prompt??

Comment: macOS: Cmd+Space to open Spotlight Search and type name to find and open the program.

Answer (score 1):

You must use

```
!pip install <package>
```

Comment: When I type in !pip install packagename, I get the following error:

Comment: twisted 18.7.0 requires PyHamcrest>=1.9.0, which is not installed.
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: And, it also says "requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn in/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages(0.19.2)"but I didn't see anything like scikit-learn myself.